# Socket.Disconnect vs Socket.Close

Tags: c#, sockets

What is the difference and which rules I must follow when working with socks?
I'm writing simple daemon, which must listen port and do some actions.

Comment: Did you check the MSDN pages for both methods?

Comment: Pro answers is allways better. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: See also regarding the proper way to clean up a Socket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62204814/222054

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Socket.Close` calls `Dispose` (but it's undocumented).

When using a connection-oriented Socket, always call the Shutdown method before closing the Socket. This ensures that all data is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed. ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown?view=netcore-3.1#remarks))

Your code should looks like this (at least I'd do it like this):

```
using (var socket = new Socket())
{
    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    socket.Close();
}
```

The `Disconnect` method takes a single parameter `bool reuseSocket` , according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect.aspx):

> reuseSocket
>   Type: System.Boolean
>   true if this socket can be reused after the current connection is closed; otherwise, false.

which basically means, when you set `reuseSocket` to `false` it will be disposed after you close it.

The `Shutdown` method will not disconnect your socket, it will just disable sending/receiving data.